# Programatically setting up Near Cache in hazelcast and Java Verify if Near cache is returning data from local cache

Tags: java, hazelcast, distributed-caching

I have created a Hazelcast set up with one node running hazelcast instance. My client application is using client config to read the cache from Hazelcast instance.
I want to implement Near cache in my client app to use it as local cache.
Could you please provide me an example where i can see how it is used in java.
My current code is this

Hazel cast cache node

```
public class HazelCastNode1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config cfg = new Config();
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
        Map<Integer, String> citiesMap = instance.getMap("Cities");

        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            citiesMap.put(i, "Vienna"+i);
        }
        System.out.println("Map Size:" + citiesMap.size()); 
    }
}
```

Client Code

```
public class ReadClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IMap<Integer, String> cumap = client.getMap("Cities");
        System.out.println(cumap.size());
    }  
}
```

Could you please give me an example which I can fit in here for Near cache implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Hi am able to figure it out this is the code

```
public class ReadClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

        NearCacheConfig ncc = clientConfig.getNearCacheConfig("Cities");
        if(ncc == null){
            ncc = new NearCacheConfig();
        }
        ncc.setCacheLocalEntries(true);
        ncc.setEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        ncc.setMaxSize(500000);
        ncc.setInvalidateOnChange(true); 
        Map<String, NearCacheConfig> nearCache =  new HashMap<String, NearCacheConfig>();
        nearCache.put("CitiesLocal", ncc);
        clientConfig.addNearCacheConfig("Cities", ncc);
          HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

        IMap<Integer, String> cumap = client.getMap("Cities");

        System.out.println(cumap.size());
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
            cumap.get(1);
        }

        System.out.println(cumap.getLocalMapStats().getNearCacheStats().getHits());
        cumap = client.getMap("CitiesLocal");
        System.out.println(cumap.size());
    }

}
```

But I still have one issue how to verify that near cache is returning data and it is not a remote call every time.

Comment: There are 2 'easy' ways. One is read out the near cache stats; this should give you information about the number of hits. Another more 'testing' approach is to see if the performance with near cache enabled is better than with near cache disabled. When it is disabled you need to make a remote call; so it will probably be an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @pveentjer, I am interested in this question too. I would like to see some logging that confirmed near cache hit. "read out the near cache stats;" - How to read out the near cache stats?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any logging if a near cache is being hit.

To read out the metrics:

```
yourmap.getLocalMapStats().getNearCacheStats().getHits()
```